# How to disable ctrl + space event in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I wants to disable intelligence in **Netbeans** while writing code.Can we change the behavior of **ctrl+space** in netbeans. Is it possible and if so then how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the behavior on this, if you go to Tools/Options/Keymap.

Then "search in shortcuts" for ctrl+space and assign any different shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it not to pop out, go to Tools|Options|Editor|Code Completion and uncheck "Auto popup completion window" and "Auto popup documentation window"

Comment: I already tried this one but not working.Changed setting and again restarted machine but still not achieved.

Comment: and for which language you want to change it?

Comment: @Iadar Need to do for Java